# SVN: Unable to delete a subfolder within a folder with RW premission

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Users are unable to delete sub-folder within a folder with full permission.

Path based Authorization File

```
   [/]  
   * = r  

   [/project] 
   @group = r


   [/project/subProject1]   
   @group = rw
```

All the user belonging to group are able to create a sub-folder/files in subProject1 followed by commit, modify a sub-folders/files followed by commit **but unable to delete a sub-folder and commit**. It says access denied. However users are able to delete files but the issue is only with subfolder created inside subProject1.

Providing access at the root or the project level works but I don't want to give access at the project level because it will allow users to create a folder at subProject level.

With the above permission

Adding a folder "test" works
   /project/subProject1/test

Adding a file "test.txt" works
   /project/subProject1/test/test.txt

Deleting a file test.txt works
   /project/subProject1/test/

Deleting the folder test doesn't work.
   /project/subProject1/test/

Subversion version 1.6.5

Comment: What protocol are you using (svn://, svn+ssh://, http://, https://)?  If http or https, what request (method and path) is failing?  You're running a very old version of Subversion, it's possible we had a bug (though I don't recall this specific one).

Comment: I am using tortoise svn (svn://) as client.

Comment: Is TortoiseSVN and the server both 1.6.5?

Comment: @Ben yes both the versions are same. Do you think this version has a bug or it is like if you want to remove a folder you need to have permission on all parent folders.

Comment: I know that permissions shouldn't bubble up.  Trying to reproduce the issue now.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this using a 1.6.5 svnserve and a 1.6.5 svn command line client (TortoiseSVN wouldn't be any different since they just use our library).  Are you sure you're using svn:// (because this sort of thing is more likely with http) and are you sure about the versions on both sides?  Right click on the working copy directory, choose Properties and switch to the SVN tab, check the URL is actually svn://

Comment: Yes i am using svn://xxx.xx.xx. It is our local server.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue here.  Can you try and reproduce the issue starting with a fresh repo and the command line client and post all the commands you ran in your question.  Perhaps there's some detail that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of a directory as a file that contains a list of the nodes that are its direct children it's much easier to understand why this doesn't work.  Adding or removing direct children of the directory is modifying the directory (or our hypothetical file that contains the list of direct children) and thus require write permission.

If you want users to be able to add or delete files in `/project` then you'll need to give them write permissions on that directory.

Note that having write permissions on `/project` doesn't give them the access to delete `/project` itself because doing so would require write  permissions on `/`.

If you're having problems with it behaving otherwise it's likely we had a bug, 1.6.5 is rather old.  I don't recall that specific issue, but if I had more info I could probably tell you for sure.

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort in resolving this issue.